# Black screen after logging into windows domain user

Tags: networking, server, login

I connected my linux Ubuntu with my windows server 2012 however when I try to logging to a domain user I get a black screen and I get sended back to my login screen. The ubuntu pc is showing in the AD computers and I linked it through likewise. Im trying to get more into Linux so I hope someone can help me with my problem.

Comment: How did you connected your Ubuntu PC to a domain controller at login?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are using xrdp to login the Ubuntu machine. Where some times restarting the xrdp in Ubuntu machine might fix this issue. Also changing the desktop manager will fix the issue.

**changing to .xsession config.**

> cd /home/youruser
>
> echo "gnome-session --session=ubuntu-2d" > .xsession
>
> sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart

Comment: I just tryed to use the; sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart command but it says that the command isn't found

Comment: Just login as root user and try the below mentioned commands.

sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart

or

sudo service xrdp restart

Comment: this is what I get when im trying to enter the commands in the root daan@ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/xrdp restart
sudo: /etc/init.d/xrdp: command not found
daan@ubuntu:~$ sudo service xrdp restart
xrdp: unrecognized service

Comment: Try without sudo command in root user  


/etc/init.d/xrdp restart

or

service xrdp restart xrdp

Comment: I just installed the xrdp program and now the command does work. I reentered all the commands but I still get a black screen when I logging to a domain user.